Match criteria THEN CountIFs
I am trying to create a formula in Google Sheets for a list of account names.
In Sheet1 I have a product list where each row contains a product, its status,m and associated account.
In another sheet I'm trying to write a formula that will perform a lookup based on a list of accounts, and return for each a count of associated products that also contain "apple"** in the product name and where the status is not "beta"
I've tried a few approaches but none work:
This returns an error:
=COUNTIFS(filter('Sheet1'!A:A, A1)'Sheet1'!A1,'Sheet1'!G:G,"* apple *",'Sheet1'!F:F,"<>beta")

This is not accurate, for example it returned 2 when I can see that it should be 11
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A:A, A1,'Sheet1'!A1,'Sheet1'!G:G,"* apple *",'Sheet1'!F:F,"<>beta")

This also is not accurate, returning 0 when it should be 1
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS('Sheet1'!A:A, A1,'Sheet1'!A1,'Sheet1'!G:G,"* apple *",'Sheet1'!F:F,"<>beta")

What is the correct formula?

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?

QUERY Function
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:G, "Select A, COUNT(A) 
   Where F != 'beta' AND  G matches '.*apple.*'
   Group by A Label COUNT(A) 'Count'",1)


